# PHP doesnt see posted data from ajax by serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form, running through jquery validation which then submits via ajax to a PHP script to handle backend functions. Ajax collects form values through serializeArray() and looks to do the job. Script fires and data is sent through(I think) to PHP. I've tried probably close to 100 combinations to receive the data at the PHP side but with no luck. I'm convinced this must be simple, something I've overlooked. Code for the ajax is below, along with a screenshot of developer tools showing what's being sent.

No matter what I try on the PHP side, I either get an empty array, NULL through $_POST/$_GET. I've tried json_decode, parsing the string, var_dump etc.

```
var data=$(form).serializeArray();
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url: "process/create_site.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    //$(form).html("<div id='message'></div>");
    //$('#message').html("<h2>Your request is on the way!</h2>")
    //  .append("<p>someone</p>")
    //  .hide()
    //  .fadeIn(1500, function() {
    //    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/ok.png' />");
    //  });
  }
});
```

[image: Image of the PHP output from ajax submission]
[image: Image of the ajax being submitted]

Comment: Try `var data=$(form).serialize();` instead. serializeArray does something slightly different. You can compare notes here: https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/ and https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. What would you have on the PHP side? Dump $_POST and then handle it from there if it works?

Comment: It would have helped if we could see your current PHP. But yes, try changing it to serialize() and then on the PHP side start with `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get. If it contains data, then you can use it for real.

Comment: So I've changed it to .serialize() and the PHP only contains var_dump($_POST); and its showing: array(0) { }

Comment: Ok. That's very strange. And you're certain that `data` in your JS contains what you're expecting?

Comment: I know!! The data within developer tools is exactly what's being input into the form. I've even tried turning validation off and then sending raw data from ajax rather than inputs and it still sees nothing. I'm wondering if it's worth a rewrite? But I don't see I would do anything different?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce through a simplified example. Can you share the html of the form and the JS code that triggers the AJAX?

Comment: and if you try to add "test" return from php to see if the connction between eatch other is good ?

Comment: @JulienBaldy I've got PHP returning json_encode data back to ajax, which logs to console. The connection is there but the data isn't. Im wondering if its being sent under something like $_REQUEST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get to the bottom of this, after an embarrassing amount of time. I'd like to post the simple reason here to help others.

The entire JS block was wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){`
which was causing the values to be stripped when posting to the PHP.

I can't find any documentation or answer to a question with a similar scenario - so here it is!